# Is the Python Tornado chat demo application thread safe?

Tags: python, tornado

I've been playing around with the [Tornado chat demo](https://github.com/facebook/tornado/blob/master/demos/chat/chatdemo.py). At a casual glance it seems like the `new_messages` method is not thread safe - it seems like items might get added to the `waiters` array while that same array is being iterated in the `for` loop.

Is this demo not thread safe?  Or, is it thread safe simply because the Python `set` object is itself thread-safe?  *Are* Python `set` objects thread safe?  I seem to find conflicting opinions on this question (and the word `set` is demonically difficult to search for effectively in Google!)

Bonus points - why is the `waiters` array set to a new `set` at the conclusion of the iteration instead of emptying the `set`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are no threads involved in Tornado applications by default.  Tornado is an event based system, so there is only one execution path.  The thing that you will need to figure out about tornado is at what moments you yield execution back to the IOLoop.

While the GIL does protect against a class of thread errors, you still can write applications that access and modify the data outside the access path of the program.

Comment: Okay, so if you are running Tornado all on it's own (not behind Apache  or nginx) and another request arrives while the first request is still actively executing (control has not released back to the IOLoop), what happens to the second request?  Does it just get refused?  Is that why Tornado is usually run behind nginx? So that nginx can at least queue up the second request and send it along when Tornado is free?

Comment: This has to do with socket listen queues.  By default tornado has a backlog queue of 128 connections before it starts refusing connections.  One of the reasons to run under nginx or the like is that since it's single threaded, if you have more than one CPU then you can use the full capability of the machine by running multiple processes.

Answer (score -1):

It's thread-safe simply because pure Python is always thread-safe. Due to the [global interpreter lock](http://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock), only one Python thread is running at any one time.

Comment: This isn't 100% correct: It's only thread safe as long as you always use atomic operations but adding to a set isn't atomic - the method doesn't use locking and the it contains several instructions, so it can be interrupted and a second thread can try to change the same structure leading to data corruption.